# Изменение правила шардирования при масштабировании БД

Tags: база-данных, postgresql, архитектура, devops, масштабирование

При шардировании БД у нас есть несколько экземпляров СУБД, и код веб сервера выбирает с каким конкретно работать по какому-то правилу на основе айдишников записей. Например, у нас есть шардирование по `userId`, и каждый сервер БД содержит данные 4-х тысяч пользователей, то есть, сервер выбирает СУБД по `userId // 4000`. И однажды вдруг меняется логика, теперь по каждому пользователю надо хранить вдвое больше данных на пользователя. Вероятно, теперь надо хранить по 2 тысячи пользователей в каждом сервере БД... Но как изменить правило шардирования и мигрировать базы данных динамически, пока сервера активно обрабатывают запросы пользователей? Надеюсь, есть что-то помимо ручного поднятия новых серверов, настройки репликации туда и т.п, всё же у нас 21й век DevOps'a. И может существует какой-то архитектурный паттерн проектирования, который может быть реализован на этапе планирования системы для того, чтобы она была адаптивна и готова к таким событиям?

Возможно универсального решения нет, поэтому я буду рад увидеть подходы к решению проблемы для любых технологий. Основной интересующий стек – Python и Postgres, но будет здорово, если эта задача уже решена и автоматизирована хоть где-то, может в MongoDB или Cassandra.

Comment: mongodb поддерживает автоматическую миграцию данных между шардами из [коробки](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/sharding-balancer-administration/#sharding-balancing).

Comment: @RomanKonoval спасибо за инфу! Ожидал такого, Монга же создавалась с упором на масштабирование. Но в нашем проекте данные довольно строго схематизированы, и нужны агрегационные запросы, поэтому в первую очередь смотрим на реляционные/аналитические СУБД. На соседнем сайте [подсказали ответ насчёт Postgres](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/419261/209061), но он какой-то слишком не автоматизированный.